# Compare row with next row in CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, comparison

I have a csv file that has rows of information. One row will tell me what its doing and the next row will tell me what it did. If it didn't do anything, it will not have that next row. I want to filter out the rows that didn't do anything. So if its missing that next row, leave there and if it has it, remove it. Here's an example of what the CSV looks like.

```
Event
Recipient Disposition: 1
Message Disposition: 1
Recipient Disposition: 2
Recipient Disposition: 3
Message Disposition: 3
Recipient Disposition: 4
Recipient Disposition: 5
Message Disposition: 5
Recipient Disposition: 6
Message Disposition: 6
```

I want just `Recipient Disposition: 2` and `Recipient Disposition: 4` filtered and the others removed.

Any ideas in PowerShell?

Comment: Is each line literally going to be formatted like that?  Some message followed by a colon followed by a number?  As an aside, this just looks like a plain old text file.

Comment: That's not a CSV file. Or a really boring one with just one column.

Comment: Did you mean 2 and 4? Because if you want to retain 1 and 4 it's unclear to me what distinguishes those two from the rest of the records.

Comment: There are other columns but ill be moving the event column to another spread sheet or txt file to separate the event without Message dispositions. The recipient disposition and message disposition will have unique information. not numbers. this is just an example.

Comment: Recipient Disposition: [554 Denied - Denied by  (Mode: normal); Mode: ; Queued: no]

Recipient Disposition: [554 Denied - Denied by  (Mode: normal); Mode: ; Queued: no]

Recipient Disposition: [250 Backend; Mode: normal; Queued: no]

Message Disposition: [250 Backend Replied [Queued mail for delivery (Mode: normal); Backend TLS: no;Policy Set: Default Inbound]

Recipient Disposition: [250 Deferred; Mode: normal; Queued: no; Frontend TLS: no; SPF: Pass]

Message Disposition: [554 Denied [CS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your example correct? From explanation shouldn't 1, 3, 5 and 6 remain?

Either way, one method you could use is to select lines you want from the file using the `Select-String` and a regex. By adding the `Context` option you can also select the next line. Pipe that into a `Where-Object` object with some logic to filter out the ones you don't want. Something like this:

```
Select-String .\your_file.txt -Pattern '^Recipient' -Context 0, 1 | ? {
    ($_.Context.PostContext -split ':\s*')[1] -eq ($_.Line -split ':\s*')[1]
} | Select line
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Line
----
Recipient Disposition: 1
Recipient Disposition: 3
Recipient Disposition: 5
Recipient Disposition: 6
```

Comment: Im looking to have the opposite of those results.

Comment: Results aside, it was the principal of how you could use the `Select-String` combined with `-Context` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heavily **edited** to better explain the script

This script does it the other way round. It stores the last line and compares with current one. The switch command acts as an `Ìf this than that` scheduler. If the current line begins with `Recipient` the `If` to check if the last line also began with is exeuted and if true the last line is output since that waas the one without a Messae following. In cas the curr. line begins with Message nothing is done. In case anything else (default) the line is output as is the case with the very first line.

```
$lines = Get-Content Test.csv
Foreach ($line in $lines) {
   switch -wildcard ($line) {
     "Recipient*"  {If ($last -match "^Recipient"){$last}}
     "Message*"    {}
     default       {$line}
  }
  $last = $line
}
```

Will show this output:

```
Event
Recipient Disposition: 2
Recipient Disposition: 4
Recipient Disposition: [554 Denied - Denied by (Mode: normal); Mode: ; Queued: no]
Recipient Disposition: [554 Denied - Denied by (Mode: normal); Mode: ; Queued: no]
```

Comment: Those are the results i want but it didnt seem to work for me. Where does it out put the information?

Comment: The last line is stored in $last. The switch acts on the content of the current line, if it begins with Recipient the command in curly braces is executed which checks with a RegEx for the begin of the var $last if it matches from begin `^` with Rec we have two successive Recipient lines and outputs the first one stored in $last.

Comment: You really should edit the question to include the more precise csv version. I appended that and rerun the script and show the result in my edited answer.

Comment: @JohnSchmalhorst Edited the asnwer to better explain the script, so see above.